# Two Queries on same table showing same row with different values?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL, but I'm pretty sure something strange is happening here.  I have a MySQL database with a table (eventtable) with 4 columns (RoomNum, EventName, EventStatus, EventDateTime).

Certain EventNames repeat with the EventStatus toggling ON and OFF at different times.  I'm trying to get the latest entry so that I have the "current" state, so I use:

```
select RoomNum, EventName, EventStatus, max(EventDateTime) as MaxDate
    from eventtable where eventName = "DND"
    group by RoomNum
```

Resulting in:
[image: eventtable_maxtime_DND_partial]

Just to make sure everything is ok, I check each room to make sure it is giving the latest one with:

```
SELECT * FROM `eventtable`
where RoomNum = "070#" and eventname = "DND" /*where "#" is a specific digit*/
order by eventdatetime asc
```

The first one looked good:
[image: eventtable_701_DND]

But then the others don't! (The EventStatus is wrong even though the time is correct):[image: eventtable_702_DND]
[image: eventtable_703_DND]
[image: eventtable_704_DND]

what I don't get is that EventDateTime matches which tells me I'm looking at the same row of data, but then how can the internal value (EventStatus) be different?

Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using below query, You can get the result as per your requirement. Please try.

select * from(select RoomNum, EventName, EventStatus, EventDateTime from eventtable where eventName = "DND" order by EventDateTime desc)tab group by RoomNum    ;

Comment: Indeed it does!  Not only does your query work (I've manually checked the entries,) it works faster than my JOIN filtering attempts too.  Now I just need to dissect your code to try and understand how you are doing what you are doing.  FYI - using an INNER JOIN so my first table can have all the columns and have the correct data takes 40s on my computer.  This search takes 1.4s!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is why firebird does not allow this.  Only this is valid

```
select RoomNum, max(EventDateTime) as MaxDate
from eventtable where eventName = "DND"
group by RoomNum
```

`EventName` and `EventStatus` values are arbitrary.  You have not told it which ones you want.  And I don't think you can.  `RoomNumn` is implicit because of `"group by"`.

To get the data you want, one way would be to use a subselect where the `max(EventDateTime)` returns a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  I don't fully understand why EventName and EventStatus would be arbitary (but I'm really new at this) problem is that it was kind of showing the right stuff too which makes it really confusing.  I guess what I will have to do (which I think I see others do) is to do a JOIN with my table that does have EventName and EventStatus where a.RoomNum = b.RoomNum AND a.EventDateTime = b.EventDateTime.  Hopefully something like that would work.

Comment: In a group by, its only looking at the values in the group by clause and the aggregate values.  It is not working on rows.  So, it cannot return a value from a particular row that that max date value was in.